# How to Calculate Active Users in a month, using date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to calculate active users in a given a month and year by the user type. I have date range for each user with start date and end date. A user with an open ended date is an active user and has to be counted from the beginning of time till current date (year month).

| USER_ID | USER_TYPE | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3673246 | INTERNAL | 1/1/2022 | 12/31/2999 |
| 1813148 | INTERNAL | 1/1/2022 | 12/31/2999 |
| 407508 | INTERNAL | 1/1/2022 | 3/1/2022 |
| 836682 | EXTERNAL | 2/1/2022 | 12/31/2999 |
| 1107520 | EXTERNAL | 2/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 |
| 2289472 | INTERNAL | 2/1/2022 | 12/31/2999 |
| 1833644 | EXTERNAL | 3/1/2022 | 12/31/2999 |

EXPECTED RESULT

| YEAR_MONTH | USER_TYPE | ACTIVE_USER_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202201 | INTERNAL | 2 |
| 202201 | EXTERNAL | 0 |
| 202202 | INTERNAL | 2 |
| 202202 | EXTERNAL | 2 |
| 202203 | INTERNAL | 1 |
| 202203 | EXTERNAL | 2 |
| 202204 | INTERNAL | 3 |
| 202204 | EXTERNAL | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this example query is what you are trying to do. However, I don't agree with your expected results. For example, in January 2022, you have an active count of 2 for "Internal", but, even adding up the users by hand, I see 3 that were active in January. Test it out yourself:

```
--Create table variable to hold test data.
DECLARE @testData TABLE (
    [user_id] int
    , user_type nvarchar(50)
    , [start_date] datetime
    , end_date datetime
);

--Load up some test data.
INSERT INTO @testData ([user_id], user_type, [start_date], end_date)
VALUES
    (3673246,'INTERNAL','1/1/2022','12/31/2999')
    ,(1813148,'INTERNAL','1/1/2022','12/31/2999')
    ,(407508,'INTERNAL','1/1/2022','3/1/2022')
    ,(836682,'EXTERNAL','2/1/2022','12/31/2999')
    ,(1107520,'EXTERNAL','2/1/2022','6/1/2022')
    ,(2289472,'INTERNAL','2/1/2022','12/31/2999')
    ,(1833644,'EXTERNAL','3/1/2022','12/31/2999')
;

--First CTE "x" is used to create a sequence of 10 numbers.
WITH x as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as x(a)
)
--Second CTE "y" creates a sequence of 1000 numbers.
, y as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY hundreds.a, tens.a, ones.a) as row_num
    FROM x as ones, x as tens, x as hundreds
)
--Third CTE "months" creates a sequence of months going back in time from today.
--To go farther back than 1000 months, modify the "y" CTE to have a "thousands" (or more) table(s).
, months as (
    SELECT
        YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as [year]
        , MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as [month]
        , CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(6))
          + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(6)),2) as YEAR_MONTH
    FROM y
)   
SELECT
    m.YEAR_MONTH
    , utype.user_type
    , COUNT(td.[user_id]) as active_user_count
FROM months as m
    --This join makes sure there is a 0 qty record for every month even
    --if there are no active users in the month for this user_type.
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_type FROM @testData) as utype
        ON 1=1

    --This joins our test data to the 2 tables above.
    --We make sure the month in m is after the users' start dates
    --and before the users' end dates.
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @testData as td
        ON td.user_type = utype.user_type
        AND (
            YEAR(td.[start_date]) <= m.[year]
            AND MONTH(td.[start_date]) <= m.[month]
        )
        AND (
            YEAR(td.end_date) >= m.[year]
            AND MONTH(td.end_date) >= m.[month]
        )
WHERE m.[year] = 2022 --Limiting results to just 2022
GROUP BY m.YEAR_MONTH
    , utype.user_type
ORDER BY m.YEAR_MONTH, utype.user_type
```

Edited to better handle the dates.