# Unify two tables with different number of rows and no common id

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to merge these two tables into one. The idea is to create a table by month and show: month, number of unique customers who bought, number of invoices, number of products, total income, total income from product A

I'm having trouble adding the total income from product A per month since the table has two rows while the other results have four.

Example of table:

| CustomerID | InvoiceID | ProductId | Date | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | A | 1/11/2016 | 600 |
| 2 | 103 | B | 12/10/2015 | 300 |

My query so far:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(date) AS month, 
    COUNT (DISTINCT customerId) AS numOfCustomers, 
    SUM(income) AS sumOfIncome, 
    COUNT(invoiceId) AS numOfInvoice,
    COUNT(productId) AS numOfProduct
FROM 
    x 
WHERE 
    YEAR(date) = 2016 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(date)

SELECT 
    MONTH(date) AS month,  
    SUM(income) AS sumOfIncomeA
FROM 
    x
WHERE 
    (productId) = 'A' 
    AND YEAR(date) = 2016
GROUP BY
    MONTH(date)
```

Comment: which database are you using, you will need a FULL OUTER JOIN to get alll combinatioons, so you must check if your database supports it

Comment: @nbk I'm using SQL server

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are you saying that you want all the months for the year listed? But, because Product A only has 2 sales (and consequently only 2 months of data) that your results are limited to 2 months? If that's the case, you want to create your list of months, and then join table x to the months table. You can create the months list in a CTE. Confirm and I'll show the example.

Comment: @TimJarosz right.

Comment: Similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74129729/2452207. In this linked question, OP was trying to get a count of active users for a year. That solution needed to first create a list of months to join the data to.

Comment: @Mimi, if these answers helped you, consider marking one of them as your accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that first creates a big list of months. You can modify the "months" CTE to go back as far as you need. By default, this query will go back 83 years from today. After you have a good list of months, then you can join your data to it so that you are guaranteed to have all the months, and only sales data if present.

```
--First CTE "x" is used to create a sequence of 10 numbers.
WITH x as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) as x(a)
)
--Second CTE "y" creates a sequence of 1000 numbers.
, y as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY hundreds.a, tens.a, ones.a) as row_num
    FROM x as ones, x as tens, x as hundreds
)
--Third CTE "months" creates a sequence of months going back in time from today.
--To go farther back than 1000 months, modify the "y" CTE to have a "thousands" (or more) table(s).
, months as (
    SELECT
        YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as [year]
        , MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as [month]
        , CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(6))
          + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())) as nvarchar(6)),2) as YEAR_MONTH
    FROM y
)   

--Main select. 
--First FROM is a list of months so that we know for a fact we have all the months in the year.
--Then do a LEFT OUER JOIN to your main data. All months will be returned.
--If there is no match in the data table, then the value will be null. 
--You can use an ISNULL(SUM(x.income),0) to convert nulls to 0.
SELECT 
    m.[month] AS month, 
    COUNT (DISTINCT x.customerId) AS numOfCustomers, 
    SUM(x.income) AS sumOfIncome, 
    COUNT(x.invoiceId) AS numOfInvoice,
    COUNT(x.productId) AS numOfProduct
FROM months as m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN x
        ON YEAR(x.[date]) = m.[year]
        AND MONTH(x.[date]) = m.[month]
WHERE 
    x.YEAR([date]) = 2016 
GROUP BY 
    m.MONTH([date])
```

Comment: Very creative use of a CTE!

Comment: @AnnL. Can't take credit. Saw it on this site somewhere.

Comment: But I would perhaps incorporate an additional one (between `y` and `months`) that defined `DATEADD(month, -1 * y.row_num, GETDATE())` once, gave it an alias, and then used the alias in `months`.

Comment: @Ann L. Yes. That's a good idea. Wrote this one for another answer so I'm not even using the one field.

Answer (score 0):

Like I wrote in the comment, as both tables could not have the same month present you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

so

The COALESCE for month is needed, as it could be that one of the month coulb be NULL

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.month,t2-month),
    t1.numOfCustomers,t1.sumOfIncome,t1.numOfInvoice,t1.numOfProduct
    ,t2.sumOfIncomeA
FROM
(SELECT 
    MONTH(date) AS month, 
    COUNT (DISTINCT customerId) AS numOfCustomers, 
    SUM(income) AS sumOfIncome, 
    COUNT(invoiceId) AS numOfInvoice,
    COUNT(productId) AS numOfProduct
FROM 
    x 
WHERE 
    YEAR(date) = 2016 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(date)) t1
FULL  OUTER JOIN
(SELECT 
    MONTH(date) AS month,  
    SUM(income) AS sumOfIncomeA
FROM 
    x
WHERE 
    (productId) = 'A' 
    AND YEAR(date) = 2016
GROUP BY
    MONTH(date)) t2 ON t1.month = t2.month
```